# How to replace all specials char but keeping the accents

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, non-ascii-characters

I would like to change all special characters in my string but I want to keep all accented ones. Is it possible with a `preg_replace()` ?

My current code:

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Hello Riskesh, this topic is not the same of your topic. :)

Comment: **@Closevoters:** the duplicate provided above is not the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Unicode:

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}0-9\-]/u', '', $string);
```

`\p{L}` is a [Unicode property](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) that matches all letters in any language, [Unicode properties on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)

Comment: Hey stema ! Thanks you for your nice reply ! That's work fine ! If I wan to no replace the   & and the single quote, how I can do that ?

Comment: The documentation for PHP seems more accurate for this question: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: @IgnacioLago, thanks for that link, added it to the answer

Comment: @Dimi, just add additional characters to your negated character class, e.g. `[/[^\p{L}0-9&\-]/]`